# Problem with semaphores and sem_wait()

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, parallel-processing, semaphore

I have a queue structure that is being used by several pthreads. The threads are supposed to dequeue from the queue if it's not empty and then do their business.

I initially had this set up as a while loop where the threads checked whether the queue was empty using a mutex_lock. Unfortunately this slowed my program down to a crawl.

I tried to implement a semaphore as the "count" variable of my queue, but unfortunately I'm running into a segfault when I try and call sem_wait(). I've found the gdb and semaphore.h don't play well together, so I'm really at a loss. I may be making a novice mistake, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Queue structure:

```
typedef struct {
  int q[QUEUESIZE+1];
  int first;
  int last;
  sem_t count;
} queue;
```

Here is the initialization of it:

```
queue *CreateQueue(void)
{
  queue *q;
  q = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
  if (q == NULL)
    return NULL;
  q->first = 0;
  q->last = 0;
  sem_init(&(q->count),0, 0);

}
```

And I make sure that I call:

```
   queue *q;
    q = CreateQueue();
```

before any threads are created.

Here is the call that seg faults

```
void *ThreadWait(void *t) {
  while(1) {
    sem_wait(&(q->count));  //THIS SEGFAULTS
    ThreadFun(); //this is the function the thread would go to to do all the work
  }
}
```

I'm hoping this is just a simple mistake on my part that I can't see right now.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: to add some clarifying code

Comment: Can you post a bit more complete code. It's not clear if you init and wait on the same sem_t. Also do you have a core file? Stack traces?

Comment: @Nikolai Thanks, I added more code, don't have a core file or stack trace. Is there a way to grab a stack trace without gdb?

Comment: Another ambiguity in your sample code is the variable `q` in `ThreadWait()`. Is this a global variable?  Could the problem be a memory over write?  Also, are you using fork() or pthreads?

Comment: @atlpeg the q in ThreadWait is a global variable. I'm using pthreads, everything was working fine (but slow) with a mutex instead of a semaphore. I've checked, and q is not defined anywhere else in my code, so I'm thinking it's not an overwrite.

Comment: @Evan, try `gcore` to get core from running process, `pstack` to get a stack trace. Also, you should check the return value of `sem_init`.

Comment: Thanks for those useful tools, as you can see it was a simpler mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `CreateQueue` in the above example is complete, then it does not seem to be setting your global `q` variable.  It assigns the results to a local variable.  But it does not seem to return the variable.

Comment: You are a miracle worker. I just noticed that it didn't return a value. Another reason to compile with -Wall. Thanks!